# Why is this code with PredicateBuilder not working?

Tags: c#, linq

Why is my list not returning anything?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<string>{ "apple" , "mango" , "chickoo", "kiwi" };
            var searchWord = new List<string>{ "a" };

            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<string>();

            foreach(var word in searchWord)
            {
                predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(word));
            }

           var qry = list.Where(predicate.Compile());

           foreach (var item in qry)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
           }

           Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

I am using Joseph Albahari's PredicateBuilder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to assign the result to your `predicate` variable:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(word));
```

The [PredicateBuilder page](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) also emphasizes an important issue:

> The temporary variable in the loop is
>   required to avoid the outer variable
>   trap, where the same variable is
>   captured for each iteration of the
>   foreach loop.

Thus, your code should resemble this:

```
        foreach(var word in searchWord)
        {
            var temp = word;
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(temp));
        }
```

Comment: @Kar no problem! This example can also be found on the [PredicateBuilder page](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) (see "Using PredicateBuilder").

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues here:

1. The `Or` extension-method does not mutate an existing expression-tree - it returns a new one. Expression-trees in general are immutable.
2. You are closing over the loop variable. To understand why this is a problem, see [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Try:

```
foreach(var word in searchWord)
{
    var wordCopy = word;
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(wordCopy));
}
```

Or even nicer:

```
var predicate = searchWord.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.False<string>(),
                   (predSoFar, word) => predSoFar.Or(p => p.Contains(word)));
```

Comment: @Ani : you are absolutely right. word should be copied to be a temporary variable. I have seen that in examples. But why?

Comment: @Ani - shorter, maybe, but I find it less readable and less intuitive since you're not accumulating something but building an expression that is later evaluated.

Comment: @tvanfosson: There is indeed an accumulation happening; why do you say there isn't? I don't understand how you are differentiating the word "building" from the word "accumulating" in this case.

Comment: @Ani - I would simply expect the Aggregate method to take some property of the collection and produce some result that represents an accumulation of that property.  In the case of a list of words, perhaps a concatenation or the average string length.  Here it produces something quite unexpected, a function that evaluates whether something else is contained in the set.  Perfectly legal use of the method, but unexpected and thus non-intuitive.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Replace: 1. concatenation => conjunction. 2. an integer representing the length of a word => a predicate representing whether a string contains a word. I think it's alright. Of course, the initialization + foreach isn't all that verbose; so it's perfectly fine not to use Aggregate if you feel it isn't intuitive here . IMO, I would think anyone messing around with expression-trees would also be familiar with the Aggregate method.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
foreach(var word in searchWord)
{
    predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(word));
}
```

I suspect it should be:

```
foreach(var word in searchWord)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(word));
}
```

In other words, just like the rest of LINQ, `PredicateBuilder` doesn't let you change the *current* predicate - it lets you build a *new* predicate based on the existing one and a new condition.

That's certainly what the [sample code](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) suggests, anyway...

When you look at the complete source code for `PredicateBuilder` (on the same page), that confirms it - the predicate is actually just an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` - i.e. an expression tree. You're not creating an instance of a `PredicateBuilder` class or anything like that. Expression trees are immutable, so the only thing `Or` *can* do is return a new expression tree, like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>
    (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
     Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2,
                                        expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: This is the first time (for c#) you are answering my question. I have only heard your tales ;). I am obliged by your answer to my question.