# PredicateBuilder returning zero records

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, predicate, predicatebuilder

I'm using PredicateBuilder to create a dynamic Where clause to query data from a DataTable.  I have a Dictionary that contains my column names and values I need to search for.  I'm simply iterating over the dictionary, if the key matches a column name, then add that key and value to the predicate.  Everything seems to work fine until the actual query is run against the datatable, I get zero records back:(  But if I replace the dynamic predicate with something like p => p["Year"] == "2010", I get records back.  Here's the code:

```
var objectList = table.AsEnumerable();
Func<DataRow, bool> predicate = GetPredicate(parms, table.Columns);

var list1 = objectList.Where(predicate).ToList();

private static Func<DataRow, bool> GetPredicate(Dictionary <string, string> parms, DataColumnCollection dataColumnCollection)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<DataRow>();
        foreach (var parm in parms)
        {
            if (dataColumnCollection.Contains(parm.Key))
            {
                var copy = parm;
                predicate = predicate.And(p => p[copy.Key] == copy.Value);
            }
        }
        return predicate.Compile();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this code with PredicateBuilder not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302382/why-is-this-code-with-predicatebuilder-not-working)

Comment: @AhmadMageed That's a completely different issue.

Comment: @AhmadMageed I did add the key and value to temp variables before including them in the predicate, didn't help:(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're starting with `false` and then adding `and` clauses.

`false && ...` always returns `false`, so your `Where` clause will never match anything.

Try starting with:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DataRow>();
```

---

ALSO:

You are closing over a loop variable, which means all your predicates will use the last `parm` in `parms`.

You can fix this by creating a local copy in your loop:

```
foreach( var parm in parms )
{
  if (dataColumnCollection.Contains(parm.Key))
  {
    var copy = parm;
    predicate = predicate.And( p => p[ copy.Key ] == copy.Value );
  }
```

---

**UPDATE:**

`DataRow[ key ]` is of type `object`, so in `p[ copy.Key ] == copy.Value`, the equality operator is object reference equality, not string equality.

You can fix this by specifying `String.Equals`:

```
predicate = predicate.And( p => String.Equals( p[ copy.Key ], copy.Value ) );
```

Interestingly, this example shows that you can have multiple instances of `string` with the same contents.

Comment: I did that before posting.  Still no records:(

Comment: What happens if you pass an empty dictionary as `parms`? You should get a copy of the entire `objectList`

Comment: You are correct, an empty dictionary object returns all records.

Comment: Well, that's good. How about with one entry in `parms` that should match one or more of the elements in `objectList`?

Comment: The dictionary I'm passing in only has a "Year" key and a "2010" value, and it's not returning any records. Though if I put in p=>p["Year"] == "2010" I get records.